# SSRS 2005 Keep textbox and textfield together when page break occurs

Tags: sql, reportingservices-2005

**Problem**
I don't have a details row or anything. I have simply a body and I dragged on textboxes for labeling textfields from my dataset. The problem is when one of the fields has too much data for the current page, it "page-breaks" at the start of the field leaving the textbox (label for the field) behind on the previous page.

**What I've tried**
 Put the data field and the textbox label

a) inside a rectangle - **didn't work**
b) inside a list and the list inside a rectangle - **didn't work**
c) inside a list with *keep together* property set to TRUE or FALSE - **didn't work**

**Question**
How would I group the textbox and the textfield so that regardless of where the pagebreak happens it includes its label?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Make it a table instead (drag a table element from toolbox) and set the keep together option to true. So the label becomes the table header, the table detail is the dataset field value and delete footer unless you need it. You get your label and your value grouped and they move around together now.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to get the detail rows to stay together, but not the group header.
Turn on Advanced Mode.  Then click on each (Static) row under the Row Group and set KeepTogether=True in each one in the Properties pane.